# I don't understand the output of xsl copy/ sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I don't understand the output, I'm getting really confused

```
<xsl:template match="t[@repeat]">
```

I'm matching `<t repeat="2">`

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="xsd:integer(@repeat)"/>
```

storing number 2

```
<xsl:variable name="result"> 
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
```

store all the child elements of , so it's only : `<t repeat="3"/>`

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $number">
    <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

shouldn't I just get `<t/> <t/>` without the attribute repeat="3"?

xsl :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xsl:template match="t">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    
        <xsl:template match="t[@repeat]">
            <xsl:variable name="number" select="xsd:integer(@repeat)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="result">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to $number">
                <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<t repeat="2">
    <t repeat="3"/>
</t>
```

output:

```
<t>
    <t/>
    <t/>
    <t/>
</t>
<t>
    <t/>
    <t/>
    <t/>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand how your result differs from what you expect. If you want to understand where each part of the result comes from, try changing:

```
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
```

to:

```
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
```

The result then will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<t repeat="2">
   <t repeat="3"/>
   <t repeat="3"/>
   <t repeat="3"/>
</t>
<t repeat="2">
   <t repeat="3"/>
   <t repeat="3"/>
   <t repeat="3"/>
</t>
```

which reflects exactly what happens as the result of applying the repeat recursively to both parent and child `t`.

Do note that your first template is never invoked during this transformation.

Comment: Why is the first template never invoked ? How does it decide which template to use when they both seem to refer to the same thing ?

Comment: The first template is not invoked because it has a priority of 0 while the second template, with a more specific match pattern, has a priority of 0.5. Even if they had the same priority, the processor would have to either choose the last template or signal an error.  If you want to force the processor to choose the other template, you can use `mode`. Recommended reading: https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/